# Aggregate function to create three different columns based of last six months, last one year and last two years

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables say A and B that I have joined, and I need the aggregated results.

(SUM) in three new columns for sales of an item located in column Item# from table A for the last six months, last one year and last two years from today's date.

I want the output to be like:

| Item# | Date | Sales Past Six Months | LAST 1 year | 2 Years |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | 200 | 1000 | 2 |
| 1 |  | 3000 | 2000 | 1 |
| 3 |  | 900 | 3000 | 1 |

I have some clue that I can apply `dateadd()` function to go back 6 months, 1 year and 2 years but clueless as to how can use this with SUM aggregate function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditional agg:

```
DECLARE @today     date = getdate();
DECLARE @sixMonths date = DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @today),
        @oneYear   date = DATEADD(YEAR,  -1, @today),
        @twoYears  date = DATEADD(YEAR,  -2, @today);  

SELECT i.Item#,
  SUM(CASE WHEN s.SaleDate >= @sixMonths THEN s.SaleTotal ELSE 0 END),
  SUM(CASE WHEN s.SaleDate >= @oneYear   THEN s.SaleTotal ELSE 0 END),
  SUM(CASE WHEN s.SaleDate >= @twoYears  THEN s.SaleTotal ELSE 0 END)
FROM dbo.Items AS i
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Sales AS s
ON i.Item# = s.Item#
GROUP BY i.Item#;
```